# z-index not working with chrome 52 , edge and safari

Tags: html, css, slider

[Problem with the image (same code) size where return after a time with SAFARI browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38683867/z-index-not-working-with-chrome-52-edge-and-safari)

What I have:

Framework:

- Jquery
- Bootstrap

What I do: I have a image slider

Browser (work,not):

- chrome version 52 (n) (same mobile result)
- firefox Version 52.0.2743.82 m (w) (same mobile result)
- Internet Explorer 11 (w)
- edge version 25.10... (n)
- Safari phone (version unknow) (n)

[Image: How looks work and not work](http://www.bilder-upload.eu/show.php?file=f8698d-1469967619.png)

**Problem:**
The overslay (see class) should just be over the **img** and then the text and button, but its ignore my z-index.

**I did delete everything wasnt is important.**

```css
/********************************/
/*       Fade Bs-carousel       */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li {
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #f39c12;
    border-color: #f39c12;
    opacity: .7;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li.active {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/********************************/
/*          Hero Headers        */
/********************************/
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
              transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}
.hero h1 {
    font-size: 6em;    
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;    
}

/********************************/
/*            Overlay           */
/********************************/
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #080d15;
    opacity: .7;
}

/********************************/
/*          Custom Buttons      */
/********************************/
.btn.btn-lg {padding: 10px 40px;}
.btn.btn-hero,
.btn.btn-hero:hover,
.btn.btn-hero:focus {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    border-color: #1abc9c;
    outline: none;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

/********************************/
/*       Slides backgrounds     */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339134316-0e91dc9ded92?q=75&fm=jpg&s=883a422e10fc4149893984019f63c818); 
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339684178-3a239570f315?q=75&fm=jpg&s=c39d9a3bf66d6566b9608a9f1f3765af);
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339276121-ba1dfa199912?q=75&fm=jpg&s=9bf9f2ef5be5cb5eee5255e7765cb327);
}

/********************************/
/*          Media Queries       */
/********************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 980px){
    .hero { width: 980px; }    
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    .hero h1 { font-size: 4em; }    
}
```

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
<title>Home</title>
<!-- Bootstramp -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font-Awesome -->

<!-- CSS-Animation -->
<!-- Fontelo -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
 <!-- Overlay -->
 <div class="overlay"></div>
 <!-- Indicators -->
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
  <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
  <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
 </ol>
 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item slides active">
   <div class="slide-1"></div>
   <div class="hero">
     <h1>Get rich</h1>
     <h3>Start now!</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Registration</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item slides">
   <div class="slide-2"></div>
   <div class="hero">
     <h1>We are smart</h1>
     <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item slides">
   <div class="slide-3"></div>
   <div class="hero">
     <h1>We are amazing</h1>
     <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>  
<!-- The scroll to top feature -->
</body></html>
```

Comment: Can you perhaps supply a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) demonstrating your problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an error calling the bootstrap.min.css try the full path

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Check it in [here](https://jsfiddle.net/o7wp4yjm/)

Comment: I didnt checked in the project, but looks like your snippet work with this perfect...maybe should change =)

Comment: I did but I dont have 15 reputation.

Answer (score 1):

You can't *(can but not recommended as if you can avoid `z-index`, avoid `z-index`)* squeeze that overlay in-between, so I made it work in another way, which I think is better.

I removed the `overlay` markup `div` and its CSS rule, and used a pseudo element instead.

If you want, you can actually add it on each slides individually if you like, having different colors and opacity, or even yet another background image.

```
/********************************/
/*            Overlay           */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel .slides:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}
```

Sample snippet

```css
/********************************/
/*       Fade Bs-carousel       */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li {
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #f39c12;
    border-color: #f39c12;
    opacity: .7;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li.active {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/********************************/
/*          Hero Headers        */
/********************************/
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
              transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}
.hero h1 {
    font-size: 6em;    
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;    
}

/********************************/
/*          Custom Buttons      */
/********************************/
.btn.btn-lg {padding: 10px 40px;}
.btn.btn-hero,
.btn.btn-hero:hover,
.btn.btn-hero:focus {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    border-color: #1abc9c;
    outline: none;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

/********************************/
/*       Slides backgrounds     */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: relative;
}

/********************************/
/*            Overlay           */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel .slides:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0; top: 0;
  width: 100%; height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339134316-0e91dc9ded92?q=75&fm=jpg&s=883a422e10fc4149893984019f63c818); 
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339684178-3a239570f315?q=75&fm=jpg&s=c39d9a3bf66d6566b9608a9f1f3765af);
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339276121-ba1dfa199912?q=75&fm=jpg&s=9bf9f2ef5be5cb5eee5255e7765cb327);
}

/********************************/
/*          Media Queries       */
/********************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 980px){
    .hero { width: 980px; }    
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    .hero h1 { font-size: 4em; }    
}
```

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
<title>Home</title>
<!-- Bootstramp -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font-Awesome -->

<!-- CSS-Animation -->
<!-- Fontelo -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">
 <!-- Indicators -->
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
  <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
  <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
 </ol>
 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item slides active">
   <div class="slide-1"></div>
   <div class="hero">
     <h1>Get rich</h1>
     <h3>Start now!</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Registration</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item slides">
   <div class="slide-2"></div>
   <div class="hero">
     <h1>We are smart</h1>
     <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item slides">
   <div class="slide-3"></div>
   <div class="hero">
     <h1>We are amazing</h1>
     <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>  
<!-- The scroll to top feature -->
</body></html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem of nesting position relative-absolute. Try this:

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="item slides active">
        <div class="overlay"></div>
        <div class="slide-1"></div>
        <div class="hero">
```

```css
/********************************/
/*       Fade Bs-carousel       */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel {
    position: relative;
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item {
    height: 100vh;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li {
    margin: 0 2px;
    background-color: #f39c12;
    border-color: #f39c12;
    opacity: .7;
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-indicators > li.active {
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  opacity: 1;
}

/********************************/
/*          Hero Headers        */
/********************************/
.hero {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    z-index: 3;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,.75);
      -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
         -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
          -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
           -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
              transform: translate3d(-50%,-50%,0);
}
.hero h1 {
    font-size: 6em;    
    font-weight: bold;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item .hero {
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
}
.fade-carousel .carousel-inner .item.active .hero {
    opacity: 1;
    -webkit-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;
       -moz-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
        -ms-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
         -o-transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s; 
            transition: 2s all ease-in-out .1s;    
}

/********************************/
/*            Overlay           */
/********************************/
.overlay {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    z-index: 2;
    background-color: #080d15;
    opacity: .7;
}

/********************************/
/*          Cu0stom Buttons      */
/********************************/
.btn.btn-lg {padding: 10px 40px;}
.btn.btn-hero,
.btn.btn-hero:hover,
.btn.btn-hero:focus {
    color: #f5f5f5;
    background-color: #1abc9c;
    border-color: #1abc9c;
    outline: none;
    margin: 20px auto;
}

/********************************/
/*       Slides backgrounds     */
/********************************/
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1, 
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2,
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  height: 100vh;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-1 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339134316-0e91dc9ded92?q=75&fm=jpg&s=883a422e10fc4149893984019f63c818); 
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-2 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339684178-3a239570f315?q=75&fm=jpg&s=c39d9a3bf66d6566b9608a9f1f3765af);
}
.fade-carousel .slides .slide-3 {
  background-image: url(https://ununsplash.imgix.net/photo-1416339276121-ba1dfa199912?q=75&fm=jpg&s=9bf9f2ef5be5cb5eee5255e7765cb327);
}

/********************************/
/*          Media Queries       */
/********************************/
@media screen and (min-width: 980px){
    .hero { width: 980px; }    
}
@media screen and (max-width: 640px){
    .hero h1 { font-size: 4em; }    
}
```

```html
<html><head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="">
<title>Home</title>
<!-- Bootstramp -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<!-- Font-Awesome -->

<!-- CSS-Animation -->
<!-- Fontelo -->
</head>
<body>
<div class="carousel fade-carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-interval="4000" id="bs-carousel">

 <!-- Indicators -->
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
  <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="0" class=""></li>
  <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="1" class=""></li>
  <li data-target="#bs-carousel" data-slide-to="2" class=""></li>
 </ol>
 <!-- Wrapper for slides -->
 <div class="carousel-inner">
  <div class="item slides active">
 <!-- Overlay -->
 <div class="overlay"></div>
   <div class="slide-1"></div>
   <div class="hero">
     <h1>Get rich</h1>
     <h3>Start now!</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">Registration</button>
   </div>
      </div>
  <div class="item slides">
   <div class="slide-2"></div>
   <div class="hero">
     <h1>We are smart</h1>
     <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
   </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item slides">
   <div class="slide-3"></div>
   <div class="hero">
     <h1>We are amazing</h1>
     <h3>Get start your next awesome project</h3>
    <button class="btn btn-hero btn-lg" role="button">See all features</button>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>  
<!-- The scroll to top feature -->
</body></html>
```

Comment: I like this solution =) Is maybe the best one to be flexible.